# My facebook app is only available with the developer account

Tags: facebook, sandbox

I created [this app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/562023303817887/) for my [facebook fanpage](http://www.facebook.com/sergioesquiveloficial).

The problem is that when I log in to the developer or admin account, the page is visible, but when everybody else logs in, it is not available.

I already disabled the sandbox option, so I don't know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Is the app in sandbox mode?

Comment: the sandbox mode is disabled but still i cant see my app outside of the developer account